# Adobe flex - custom tooltip text for plotseries

Tags: flash, apache-flex, tooltip, adobe

I have a plotseries being displayed in Adobe Flex with CircleItemRenderer. By default, the tooltip on any data point is showing a predefined value. I want to change the content of the text. How can I do that?

Thank you very much,
Raja.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the text of the tooltip, use the dataTipFunction of the Chart component.

Check this [Flex Chart documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/ChartBase.html#dataTipFunction)